# How to show that a given set is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having some issues with this problem in my Linear Algebra textbook. The goal is to either show that the given set, $W$, is a vector space, or to find a specific example to the contrary:

\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c\\ 
d
\end{bmatrix} :
\begin{matrix}
3a + b = c\\ 
a + b + 2c = 2d
\end{matrix}
\end{Bmatrix}

I understand the basic properties of Vector Spaces - such as having to contain the zero vector, being closed under addition, and being closed under scalar multiplication. I have no problem proving when these sets are *not* vector spaces, for example if they do not contain the zero vector.

This set appears to contain the zero vector (if you plug in $0$ for $a, b, c, d$ the equations are consistent). But I'm not quite sure how to *prove* that this set is a vector space, or how to prove that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you learnt about vector subspaces? You can prove that this space is a vector space by exhibiting it as a vector subspace of a known vector space, for example, $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Yes, I have learned about subspaces. Could you elaborate on this? I'm guessing this is an easier alternative to showing closure under addition and multiplication.

Comment: To show a subset is a vector subspace you need to check that the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and it contains 0. The answers below show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a vector satisfying the two constraints then multiplying by $k$ you get $$3a+b=c \implies 3(ka)+(kb)=(kc)$$ $$ a + b + 2c = 2d \implies (ka) + (kb) + 2(kc) = 2(kd)$$ so you have closure under scalar multiplication.  Similarly for addition $$3a_1+b_1=c_1 \text{ and }3a_2+b_2=c_2 \\ \implies 3(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)=(c_1+c_2)$$ $$a_1 + b_1 + 2c_1 = 2d_1 \text{ and }a_2 + b_2 + 2c_2 = 2d_2 \\ \implies (a_1+a_2) + (b_1+b_2) + 2(c_1+c_2) = 2(d_1+d_2)$$

Comment: This one seems to be the most tangible and straightforward answer for me, so I'll pick it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Verify all conditions that define a vector space one by one. For example, you have to verify that if $u$ and $v$ are two vectors that satisfy the given equations and if $\alpha$ is a constant (an element of the underlying field) then $\alpha \times u$ is a solution and $u+v$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithmic approach:
If the given set was to contain vectors u, v and constant c
Then go down the list below and make sure all constraints in your problem are met through trial.

Can u and v exist in this space?

1. Addition:

(a) u + v is a vector in V (closure under addition).

(b) u + v = v + u (Commutative property of addition ).

(c) (u+v)+w = u+ (v+w) (Associative property of addition).

(d) There is a zero vector 0 in V such that for every u in V
we have (u + 0) = u (Additive identity).

(e) For every u in V , there is a vector in V denoted by −u such
that u + (−u) = 0 (Additive inverse).

2. Scalar multiplication:

(a) cu is in V (closure under scalar multiplication0.

(b) c(u + v) = cu + cv (Distributive propertyof scalar mult.).

(c) (c + d)u = cu + du (Distributive property of scalar mult.).

(d) c(du) = (cd)u (Associate property of scalar mult.).

(e) 1(u) = u (Scalar identity property).

Remark.
 It is important to realize that a vector space consisits of four
entities:

1. A set V of vectors.
2. A set of scalars. In this class, it will alawys be the set of real
   numbers R. (Later on, this could be the set of complex numbers
   C.)
3. A vector addition denoted by +.
4. A scalar multiplication.

Comment: In this class… this is plagiarism